# Reverse-engineer a pom.xml given a lib folder full of jars?

Tags: maven

Title says it all.

Is it possible to reverse-engineer pom.xml dependencies given a lib folder full of jars?

i.e. Discover the publicly available Maven artifacts given a jar name and/or SHA1 checksum.

Here's a naive attempt which didn't work very well, because the search often returns too many matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Mavenize a lib folder, converting jars into dependencies

import os
import sys
import urllib2
import json

for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
        url = "http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?rows=1&wt=json&q=" + file
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        jsonStr = response.read()
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
        if(jsonObj["response"]["numFound"] > 0):
                print "<dependency><!-- for " + file + "-->"
                print "  <groupId>" + jsonObj["response"]["docs"][0]["g"] + "</groupId>"
                print "  <artifactId>" + jsonObj["response"]["docs"][0]["a"] + "</artifactId>"
                print "  <version>" + jsonObj["response"]["docs"][0]["latestVersion"] + "</version>"
                print "</dependency>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If those jar files produced by maven then yes it is possible. In other case it is not possible without extra step like trying to find group id and version from mvnrepository etc.